# Is there a Google javascript plugin which allow website to get user's email with single click?

Tags: google-signin, google-account, google-api-javascript-client

Is there a google email javascript product/SDK that provide user with just a single click button to subscribe to a newsletter on the website with the signed account.

I think I saw one on some website but I cant remember and searched but wasnt able to find something like that.